# PHP -Parsing and echo a file and change line whether detect a specific string(e.g \t:\t)

Tags: php, string, file, parsing, detect

hello i have i problem echo content from a file.

What i want is parse and echo a file and change line whether detect  a specific string(e.g \t:\t) in it.

Here is my current code

---

```
$full_file_name_exif_txt = "downloaded2/PisaTower/$entry.exif.txt";

if (file_exists($full_file_name_exif_txt) )

 {

   $file = @fopen($full_file_name_exif_txt, "r");

   while (!feof($file)) 

       {

         if(strpos(file_get_contents("downloaded2/PisaTower/$entry.exif.txt"), " : ")) 

          {

            echo "I found \t:\t and i changed line <br/>";

          }

       }

       fclose($file)

       echo file_get_contents("downloaded2/PisaTower/$entry.exif.txt");

      }
```

my text file contents

---

IPTC:CodedCharacterSet : UTF8 IPTC:ApplicationRecordVersion : 105 IFD1:Compression : JPEG (old-style) IFD1:ResolutionUnit : inches IFD1:ThumbnailOffset

expectet text file output

---

IPTC:CodedCharacterSet

: UTF8 IPTC:ApplicationRecordVersion

: 105 IFD1:Compression

: JPEG (old-style) IFD1:ResolutionUni

t: inches IFD1:ThumbnailOffset

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to find `<space>:<space>` or `<tab>:<tab>`?

Comment: im trying to find <space>:<space> and every time i find it i want to print the content and change line.

Comment: Okay, when you put `"\t"` that means `<tab>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest changing `file_exists()` to `is_file` and I'd suggest moving your `file_get_contents` to just after that, and put the value in a variable like

```
$contents=file_get_contents("downloaded2/PisaTower/$entry.exif.txt");
```

That way you don't have to keep reading from the disk (or network)

Then, I'd suggest

```
$lines=explode(' : ',$contents);
foreach($lines as $line)
{
   echo $line."\n<br>";
}
```

Notice that I used double quotes `"` at the end of the echo. That allows the newline `\n` to be parsed.

Comment: I realized I answered a little hastily, so it might not be perfect, but hopefully it'll point you in the right direction. I might tweak this later.

Answer (score 0):

Do you look at the result with a browser (opposed to in a shell console) ? The carriage return et tab are not displayed in HTML (replaced by a unique blank space).

The nl2br() function may be of some use in this case.

And you will have to replace \t by some &nbsp; html entities or some css decoration.